# Fitting a function to a set of data with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question here, but I'm a real noob concerning gnuplot so please be patient.

I have a set of data and tried to fit it with

```
       f(x)=a * cos(x-b)**2 via a,b.
```

But it didn't work. It should look like this,

[image]

but it turned out like this
[image]

What could be the Problem with my fit equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nonlinear fit converged to a local minimum, not the global one. You need to start fitting closer to the global minimum (which you as a human can find much more easily than a computer).

So you need to specify starting values for a and b that are closer to what you expect, via

a = ...

b = ...

before you call fit.

Have a look at this documentation section:

http://theochem.ki.ku.dk/on_line_docs/gnuplot/gnuplot_21.html#SEC77